# Select MAX and add 1 (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ranking-functions

```
DROP TABLE #ID
CREATE TABLE #ID (ID INT)
INSERT INTO #ID (ID)
VALUES (24),(65),(77),(44)

DECLARE @ID int
SELECT @ID =  MAX(ID) from #ID

DROP TABLE #name
CREATE TABLE #NAME (Name char (20))
INSERT INTO #NAME (name)
VALUES ('Ben'),('Alex'),('Mark') 

DROP TABLE #abc
CREATE TABLE #ABC (ID INT, Name char(20))
INSERT INTO #ABC (ID,Name)
SELECT @ID,name
FROM #name

SELECT * FROM #ABC
```

I want the process to pick up the maximum ID from #ID and then add 1 for the next record. So, expected result should be:

```
ID  Name
77  Ben                 
78  Alex                
79  Mark
```

Please help me getting around this logic without using cursors. Can I use IDENTITY(@ID,1) in any way? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Replace:**

```
Select * from #ABC
```

**For:**

```
Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID)  + ID - 1, Name from #ABC
```

[Working fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/13279)